how to execute both return and redirect on next js api response
I'm working on a Next.js project where I want to redirect the user after a successful login, but also return the user data for further processing. Here’s my code:
if (response.data.user) {
    redirect(`/dashboard/${response.data?.user?.role}`);
    return { success: true, data: { user: response.data.user } };
} else {
    throw new Error('Login failed. Please try again.');
}

However, as soon as the redirect function is called, it prevents the return from executing, meaning the user is redirected but the data is never returned.
How can I make both the redirect and return happen so that the user is redirected and the function still returns the data?
Is there a specific way to handle this in Next.js or JavaScript in general? Any help would be appreciated!
I was expecting both the redirect to happen and the function to return the data, allowing me to redirect the user while also handling the return value for other logic.

Is this a HTTP API you're talking about? Then you just cannot - at best you can pass URL parameters to the redirect route.

You can fetch the data from your dashboard page instead as a workaround

Thanks, i have solved it by moving the redirect to the dashboard page where i'm invoking the getUser server action.
